# Select top 5 items from each group using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there any 1-2 lines solution to select the top five items from each group using PowerShell?

For example, group processes returned by [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) by name and see the first three wp3 processes.

Of course I can iterate by each unique name, but I hope there is a shorter solution.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here you are, using `Get-Process` as you did previously.

```
Get-Process | Group-Object ProcessName | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Select-Object -First 5
}
```

That will group things by property, and then for each group re-expand the group to its original form, and select the first 5 entries.

I suppose you could sort in there too before the `Select-Object -First 5` pipe to only get the top CPU usage properties for it or something too and not just 5 seemingly random ones.

Comment: So verbose ;) `get-process|group name|%{$_.group[0..4]}`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Verbosity is explicit clarity. In a written script and especially in a tutorial, it's best practice to use the full command name. Simply put, aliases change, and you can't be certain they will exist on every system or every version of PowerShell (particularly with PowerShell 6+). Aliases should be reserved for ad-hoc statements at the command line, not formal writing that needs to be portable or understood by an audience larger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, perhaps `Format-Table -GroupBy ProcessName` would be a better option e.g.:

```
Get-Process | Format-Table -GroupBy ProcessName
```

Comment: Maybe its a good solution if you want to output the result to screen, but I need just an resulting array.

Comment: Well you said `" and *see* first 3 wp3 processes"`.  :-)

Comment: Oh, I see :), sorry for misleading.